# Java Mockito.when failing with StringBuilder as parameter

Tags: java, mockito

Below is the JUnit Test, `oneLoginAuthUtil` is Mocked. But `Mockito.when` is returning `null`. **`oneLoginAuthUtil.getMetaData`** is always `null`. Below is the code -

```
public void func() throws Exception {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("test");
    RequestContext context = new RequestContext();
    Mockito.when(oneLoginAuthUtil.getMetaData(context, b)).thenReturn("abcdef");
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = loginControllerImpl.handleGetMetaDataEndPointImpl(context);
}

public String getMetaData(RequestContext context, StringBuilder b) throws Exception {
    Auth auth = getOneLoginAuthObject(context);
    final Saml2Settings settings = auth.getSettings();
    String metadata = settings.getSPMetadata();
    List<String> errors = Saml2Settings.validateMetadata(metadata);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        b.append(errors.toString());
        throw new SSOException("metadata_validation_error");
    }
    return metadata;
}

public ResponseEntity<Object> handleGetMetaDataEndPointImpl(RequestContext context) {
    try {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        String metadata = oneLoginAuthUtil.getMetaData(context, b);
        log.info(metadata);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(metadata, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("<error>Exception: " + e.getMessage() + "</error>", new HttpHeaders(),
                HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

But `oneLoginAuthUtil.getMetaData` method without `StringBuilder` as parameter works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same objects `context` and `b` for actual call and `when().thenReturn()`? Show full code of test with actual call of `getMetaData` function.

Comment: Where is the return statement of the `getMetadata` method ?

Comment: Added the full code.

Answer (score 5):

It returns `null` because when you mock a method using specific instances as parameters, Mockito will return the mapped return value if and only if the parameters provided while testing are equal to the parameters that you provided while mocking which is obviously not the case. Mockito did not have a match so it returns the default value for a method that returns an object called on a mock which is `null`.

In other words `Mockito.when(oneLoginAuthUtil.getMetaData(context, b))` is equivalent to `Mockito.when(oneLoginAuthUtil.getMetaData(Mockito.eq(context), Mockito.eq(b)))`, here as the class `StringBuilder` doesn't override the method `equals(Object obj)`, the instance provided while mocking is not equal to the instance provided while testing as they are not the same instance (the only possibility to be equal when relying on the default implementation of `equals(Object obj)`) such that you get this behavior.

So you should use `Mockito.any(StringBuilder.class)` to match with any instances of type `StringBuilder` such that the instances don't need to be equal anymore, your code would then be:

```
Mockito.when(
    oneLoginAuthUtil.getMetaData(Mockito.eq(context), Mockito.any(StringBuilder.class))
).thenReturn("abcdef");
```

Assuming that your main class is `LoginControllerImpl` and that it has a member field `oneLoginAuthUtil` of type `OneLoginAuthUtil`, you could use the annotation `@InjectMocks` to inject directly your mock of type `OneLoginAuthUtil`, the complete code would then be:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginControllerImplTest {

    @Mock
    private OneLoginAuthUtil oneLoginAuthUtil;
    @InjectMocks
    private LoginControllerImpl loginControllerImpl;

    @Test
    public void func() throws Exception {
        RequestContext context = new RequestContext();
        Mockito.when(
            oneLoginAuthUtil.getMetaData(
                Mockito.eq(context), Mockito.any(StringBuilder.class)
            )
        ).thenReturn("abcdef");

        ResponseEntity<Object> response 
            = loginControllerImpl.handleGetMetaDataEndPointImpl(context);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. But the problem is with StringBuilder as param, if I just have RequestContext Mockito.when works just fine.

Comment: ah ok so use any for StringBuilder and eq for RequestContext

Comment: No still null. Below is the code  StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("test");
        RequestContext context = new RequestContext();
        Mockito.when(oneLoginAuthUtil.getMetaData(Mockito.eq(context), Mockito.any(StringBuilder.class))).thenReturn("abcdef");

Comment: use any for both then if it still doesn't work, your problem is elsewhere as it works properly on my side

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuilder` does not implement `equals()` or `hashCode()`, so it can't be used for argument matching like that.

The problem really is that you shouldn't be passing a mutable object (such as `StringBuilder`) into your test subject. Why does returning "metadata" require you to append to a `StringBuilder` outside your scope?

Comment: StringBuilder is used to append errors in metadata and log these errors back in func()